# Long type is not used in range() function

Tags: python, loops, long-integer

I know in python we do not define the data types, but I have a particular number which  is of  long type, I had a loop using that value as the final parameter of the range function, when I complied and implemented it, it showed an error which was similar to this "long is not used for an  iteration, please help me.

Comment: how did you compile it? why didn't you post the actual error message, instead of one similar to it?

Comment: please provide the code also with your questions always .

Answer (score -2, accepted):

in place of range() function please use xrange() function